# How to make a particular action publicly available while keeping everything else private

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, role

I was able to successfully implement FormsAuthentication and use the Authorize Attribute to control which roles are authorized to access the different controllers and actions.  I want to allow one particular action to be publicly available but It always send me to the login form.

I've tried using

```
[Authorize(Users="?")]
```

or

```
[Authorize(Users="*")]
```

but both send me to the login form.

however
    [Authorize(Users="Admin")]
will only send non admin user to the login form as expected.  Is this possible to do?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do by following this article:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx